# Batch string replace after special character

Tags: windows, batch-file

In batch, how can replace the substring after a special character.

```
@echo off

set var1=abc_123
set var2=%var1:*_=%
echo %var2%

set var1=abc_123
set var3=%var1:_*=%
echo %var3%
```

output:

```
123
abc_123
```

In `set var2=%var1:*_=%`, the `*`match the `abc`, but in `set var3=%var1:_*=%` it doesn't work!

What's the difference between the two usage?
How can I use `*` or something to replace the `_123`

Comment: The search expression `*_` in the first section means *»everything up to the first `_`«* because the `*` is at the beginning, whereas the search expression `_*` in the second section means *»`_` followed by `*`«*…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the search/replace syntax it's not possible, because the asterix is used as wildcard only when it's the first character in the search expression, at any other position it's treated as normal character.

But for a single character it can be done with a FOR /F loop.
It splits the text by the delimiter character(s) into tokens.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=_" %%L in ("%var1%") DO (
  set var3=%%L
)
echo %var3%
```

Comment: It works. But I also want to know why the code I post does not work. Because the replace is simpler than the for.

Comment: @stonecutter you think a half dozen lines of code is simpler than one line of code?  I highly recommend you learn how to use a `FOR F` command as it comes in handy for a lot of tricks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for simpler, then perhaps this is what you're looking to achieve:

```sh
Set "var1=abc_123"
Echo(%var1%
Set "var2=%var1:*_=%"
Echo(%var2%
Set "var3=%var1:_="&:"%"
Echo(%var3%
```

Simpler of course refers only to using expansion and replacement, not the understanding of the technique. If you want to learn more about the technique, please take a look at the examples in [this external site thread](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429).

Comment: Thank you for letting future readers know that this addresses your asked question. I just thought, however, I'd mention that your question asks for 'substring after a special character'. So if the initial variable was `abc__123`, the substring after `_` would be `_123` and before that `abc`, which is exaclty what my code above does. However the `for` method, you've now accepted, would return `123` and `abc` in exactly the same way as it would for and initial value of `abc_123`! There is a difference.